# get row id of mysql database into onclick function and pass to function using codeigniter

Tags: php, mysql, codeigniter, phpmyadmin

hey guys i am a beginner of **`CodeIgniter`** framework, I am making a application in which i want to delete records/rows from database. I created delete button in front of every row on the view, for this action I wrote some code but it is not helpful. Please help me.

This is my **`view`**:

```
<td><?php echo anchor('dbcont/deleteinput', 'Delete', array('onclick'=>'deleteinput(\''. $row->member_id .'\');')); ?></td>
```

This is my **`model`**:

```
function deletedata($id)
{
     $this->db->delete('tbl_members', array('member_id' => $id));
}
```

This is my **`controller`**:

```
function deleteinput($id)
    {
            $this->load->helper('form');
            $this->load->helper('html');
            $this->load->model('user');
            $this->db->select('member_id');
            $id = $this->db->get('tbl_members');
            $this->user->deletedata($id);
            redirect('home');
    }
```

Comment: are you getting row_id using $row->member_id perfectly

Comment: @Venkat yeah but it come in the form of string . . like '25' . . i want it like 25 . . just without single quote

Comment: are you getting it from database.......

Comment: convert that string id to integer using intval($row->member_id) and pass to your function

Comment: @Venkat hey bro its not working..intval($row->member_id) this not convert the string into integer . . any other idea  . .

Comment: first of all why it is coming as string if you are getting it directly form database check database what it is whether it is string or int in database?

Comment: @Venkat member_id is primary key,int and auto increment

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/24739/discussion-between-venkat-and-jay)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you are calling a javascript function on click event... but you don't have any function in the posted question..

```
 <td><?php echo anchor('dbcont/deleteinput', 'Delete', array('onclick'=>'deleteinput(\''. $row->member_id .'\');')); ?></td>
```

anyways i don't think you need javascript function you can just pass id as parameter in url

try this,

```
 <td><?php echo anchor('dbcont/deleteinput/'.$row->member_id, 'Delete'); ?></td>
```

note: dbcont is controller class name

**update**

update you controller...

```
function deleteinput($id)
{
        $this->load->helper('form');
        $this->load->helper('html');
        $this->load->model('user');
        $this->user->deletedata($id);
        redirect('home');
}
```

you don't need to `get()` and `select` anything in you controler..this is models code...and you are already doing that in your `deletedata` function..

> $this->db->delete() => The first parameter is the table name, the second is the where clause. You can also use the where() or or_where() functions instead of passing the data to the second parameter of the function.

[docs](http://ellislab.com/codeigniter/user-guide/database/active_record.html) here

Comment: ok.. `echo $id;exit;` in first line of `deleteinput($id)` function .. and check if you are gettin the id or not..

Comment: yeah i am getting the id . .

Comment: then there is something worng in your model...check it...`echo $this->db->last_query();exit;` inside `deletedata` function after `db->delete` adn check what you get in query

Comment: i did it by this post thanx..a little mistake is that '<td><?php echo anchor('"dbcont/deleteinput/".$row->member_id, 'Delete'); ?></td>'

Answer (score 0):

try this also...

```
<td><a href="javascript:delete_member(<?php echo $row->member_id  ?>) > Delete</a></td>
```

And in the same view file write JavaScript function like this.......

```
function delete_membet(member_id){
       window.location.href = "<?php echo ROOT_FOLDER ?>/controller_name/delete/" +member_id ;
 }
```

Then in the controller file write a function like this below....

```
public function delete($member_id)

 {

        $this->model_file->delete($member_id);

        redirect('home');

  }
```

In the model file write a function like this.........

```
   public function delete($member_id)

     {
         $query = "delete from members where member_id = $member_id";

            $res = $this->db->query($query);
      }
```

Comment: Severity: Warning

Message: Missing argument 1 for Dbcont::deleteinput()

Filename: controllers/dbcont.php

Line Number: 66

Comment: what is there in line number66

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
<a href="javascript:void(0);" onclick="deleteinput(<?php echo $row->member_id;?>);">delete</a>
```

Use this in your javascript

```
<script type="text/javascript">
var url="<?php echo base_url();?>";

    function delete(id){ 
        if (confirm("Do you want to delete?"))
          window.location = url+"dbcont/deleteinput/"+id;
        else
          return false;
}
</script>
```

In controller

```
public function deleteinput($id){
     $this->load->model('user');
     $this->user->deletedata($id);
     redirect('home');

}
```

In Model

```
function deletedata($id){
        $this->db->where('id', $id);
        if($this->db->delete('tbl_members'))
           return true;
        else
           return false;
    }
```